# Why does my Groovy println always return null after correct statement?

Tags: string, groovy, null, tostring

I'm extremely new to groovy and I'm wondering why I'm receiving null after my code. I've got an App.groovy and a Person.groovy which are both very basic, and I think my error is in the auto return for closings but I'm not sure

```
package firstGradleGroovyBuild

class App {
    static void main(def args) {
        def myList = [1,2,"James","4"]

        myList.each {
            println("$it is of ${it.class}")
        }
        println()

        Person person = new Person()
        person.age = 13
        person.address = "Home"
        println(person)

        Person p2 = new Person()
        p2.firstName = "Joe"
        p2.lastName = "Shmo"
        p2.age = 23
        p2.address = "Away"
        println p2

        Person p3 = new Person(firstName: "Smoky", lastName: "Robinson", age: 24, address: "Mountains")
        println p3
    }
}
```

So here is my App, and I'm just trying to test a few different things. 

First I wanted to make sure that, without setting a first and last name, I would receive null in their place. 

Second I just wanted to test normal property setting

Third I wanted to test the auto default constructor initializing props. 


I've also tried replacing p2 w/ tap{} after looking at documentation (didn't work), but I think this is because tap is solely used as a preference to save on typing the prefix p2 over and over when updating an instance.

```
Person p2 = new Person().tap {
            firstName = "Jo"
            lastName = "Mo"
            age = 23
            address = "Away"
        }
        println p2
```

Here is my Person class

```
package firstGradleGroovyBuild

class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    int age
    def address

    String toString(){
        println("${firstName} ${lastName} of age ${age} lives at ${address}")
    }

}
```

My output is **almost** as expected: Everything in the println's is correct.

```
1 is of class java.lang.Integer
2 is of class java.lang.Integer
James is of class java.lang.String
4 is of class java.lang.String

null null of age 13 lives at Home
null
Joe Shmo of age 23 lives at Away
null
Smoky Robinson of age 24 lives at Mountains
null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But I'm getting a "null" after every println. Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seen, `println` returns null

So in your `toString`, you're printing out the String, then returning `null`

`toString` shouldn't do any printing.

Change your class to:

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    int age
    def address

    String toString(){
        "${firstName} ${lastName} of age ${age} lives at ${address}"
    }
}
```

And everything will be fine :-)

Comment: My goodness... THANK YOU. I'd upvote you but my rep is too low lol. *edit*.. just got to 15. here you go kind stranger.

Comment: 20 now No worries!  Glad I could help!